# How to make this as user defined function in R programing

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to make a user defined function with two inputs. and for input it has a condition
i.e : The user should be able to specify the product  (Gold/Silver/Platinum) and time period (Year or Months ) and the function should take this inputs while identifying the top 10 Customers.

Data frame

```
head(customer_repay,20)
   Customer Age      City Product  Limit Company       Segment      Month Repayment Amount Year Months    Amount
1        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2004-01-12        495414.75 2004    Jan 495414.75
2        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2004-01-03        245899.02 2004    Jan 245899.02
3        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2004-01-15        259490.06 2004    Jan 259490.06
4        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2004-01-25        437555.12 2004    Jan 437555.12
5        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2005-01-17        165972.88 2005    Jan 165972.88
6        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2005-02-23        365366.62 2005    Feb 365366.62
7        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2005-02-01         14473.41 2005    Feb  14473.41
8        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2004-01-12        350446.82 2004    Jan 350446.82
9        A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2004-02-05        117964.43 2004    Feb 117964.43
10       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2006-04-19         79849.19 2006    Apr  79849.19
11       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2005-11-22        402099.78 2005    Nov 402099.78
12       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2006-11-21        169358.40 2006    Nov 169358.40
13       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2005-07-03        297176.74 2005    Jul 297176.74
14       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2006-09-03        186427.50 2006    Sep 186427.50
15       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2005-02-23         96670.70 2005    Feb  96670.70
16       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2006-04-01        429099.97 2006    Apr 429099.97
17       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2004-01-15        453027.64 2004    Jan 453027.64
18       A1  76 BANGALORE    Gold 500000      C1 Self Employed 2005-02-16        187398.64 2005    Feb 187398.64
19       A2  71  CALCUTTA  Silver 100000      C2  Salaried_MNC 2004-01-03        185955.07 2004    Jan 100000.00
20       A2  71  CALCUTTA  Silver 100000      C2  Salaried_MNC 2005-02-28        412783.34 2005    Feb 100000.00
>
```

i have written this piece of code .

```
if (Prod %in% c('Gold','Silver','Platinum') & Time %in% c('Year','Months')) {
  df_result<-customer_repay%>%group_by(Months,City,Product,Customer)%>%summarise(Repayment = sum(`Repayment Amount`))
  View(df_result)
}else{
  print('Enter the correct Parameter.')
}
```

Comment: [r4ds](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html) is a helpful resource for ramping up with R and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general starting point, you can use the code you've already developed to get to this point:

```
name_of_function <- function(
  df, # data frame
  Prod, # product
  Time # time
)
{
  
  # Require "magrittr" package for `%>%`
  require(magrittr)
  
  # Check if product and time are valid
  if (Prod %in% c('Gold','Silver','Platinum') & Time %in% c('Year','Months')) {
    df_result <- df %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(Months, City, Product, Customer) %>% 
      dplyr::summarise(Repayment = sum(`Repayment Amount`))
  }else if(!Prod %in% c('Gold', 'Silver', 'Platinum')){
    # Invalid product
    stop(
      "Product input into 'Prod' is not valid."
    )
  }else if(!Time %in% c('Year', 'Months')){
    # Invalid time
    stop(
      "Time input into 'Time' is not valid."
    )
  }
  
  # Top 10 customers (based on repayment)
  df_result <- df_result[order(df_result$Repayment, decreasing = TRUE),]
  result <- df_result[1:10,]
  
  # Returns data frame
  return(result)
  
}

# Use function with `customer_repay` data frame
name_of_function(
  df = customer_repay,
  Prod = "Gold",
  Time = "Year"
)
```

The function assumes that you would like the top 10 customers based on their value of repayment.

Comment: How Can i get top 10 customer for each city on the basis of Repayment .